# How to have an interactive terminal after a task in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, task

I have a simple task running a cmd file

```json
    {
        "label": "dune utop",
        "command": "dune_utop.cmd"
    }
```

I'd like to be able to interact with the terminal in which my cmd was executed - like send command line - is this possible ?